# Are atoms more attracted to each other when you raise or lower the the temperature?

Tags: temperature

Are atoms more attracted to each other when you raise or lower the temperature?

Comment: Well the [Coulomb potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coulomb's_law) seems to be independent of temperature, so can you explain why you might think the temperature might affect the attractive force?

Comment: Because once you get past the Coulomb potential you see the Strong Nuclear force. Works for Deuterium

Answer (score 1):

Temperature is connected with the kinetic degrees of freedom of the atoms or molecules . In a gas , [temperature is given by](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinetic_theory#Temperature_and_kinetic_energy)

[image: temperature]

directly proportional to the root mean square of velocity, an average kinetic energy.

Raising the temperature raises the probability of atoms/molecules scattering against each other.

Attraction with neutral atoms and molecules comes from their [spill over electric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waals_force) fields ,  and their  intrinsic magnetic  fields. These are not enhanced by the higher kinetic energies. When the temperature is lowered enough to the level of the binding energies of the attractive potentials then the answer is lowest temperatures allow for binding : example, water turns to ice, which holds the molecules tightly.